# nvm not downloading on mac

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I want to install `nodejs` and `npm`(node package manager) using `nvm`(node version manager) because I have permission problems when installing it using the `nodejs` installer.

I checked the nvm page to see how to install it:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

But when I run the following command (with or without sudo), download does not start:

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

Note that curl is installed on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the v0.34.0 download is down.

I tried to install an earlier version and download succeeded as well as install:

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash